# Truffle Console error : invalid number value. Value must be an integer, while executing commands from a tutorial

Tags: truffle, truffle-console

I am trying to execute commands from the following tutorial:

[medium Dev Tutorial](https://medium.com/@JusDev1988/reentrancy-attack-on-a-smart-contract-677eae1300f2)

I am getting an integer error while executing a command:

```
truffle(ganache)> balanceInEth = address => web3.utils.fromWei(getBalance(address).toString(), 'wei')
```

[Function: balanceInEth]

```
truffle(ganache)> balanceInEth(victim.address)
```

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:57187   throw
> new Error('[number-to-bn] while converting number ' +
> JSON.stringify(arg) + ' to BN.js instance, error: invalid number
> value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance.
> Note, decimals are not supported.');

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the medium article you've referred, it looks like the `balanceInEth` function is just a reference to `web3.eth.getBalance`. The function returns a Promise which resolves into a string.

`getBalance(address).toString()` would convert the Promise into a string and not the result returned by the Promise. You can use async-await to wait for the promise to complete.

```
balanceInEth = async(address) => web3.utils.fromWei(await getBalance(address))
```